# Difference between these 2 methods that return the same value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi can anybody tell me the difference between these methods?

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBookings(int id)
        {
            Bookings bookings = db.Bookings.Find(id);

            if (bookings == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(bookings);
    }
```

and

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBookings(int id)
        {
            

            Bookings bookings = (from tbBooking in db.Bookings
                                 where tbBooking.BookingsID == id
                                select new Bookings
                             {
                                 BookingsID = tbBooking.BookingsID,
                                 CheckinDate = tbBooking.CheckinDate,
                                 CheckoutDate = tbBooking.CheckoutDate,
                                 CheckedIn = tbBooking.CheckedIn,
                                 Room = tbBooking.Room,
                                 HostelID = tbBooking.HostelID,
                                 UserID = tbBooking.UserID
                             }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (bookings == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(bookings);
    }
```

So the first one runs fine but the second method return the following error

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not >handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The entity or complex type 'MyProject.Models.Bookings' cannot be >constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Do they both not return a bookings object so therefore should be identical?

The reason I ask is that I keep getting a "Sequence contains more than one element" error when the first method is used in deployment on Azure, but runs fine when ran locally so a so a number of websites I found a soulution to the FirstOrDefault() to the LINQ query so I then had to include the linq query but my issue now is the above error.

Ahy ideas/advice would be great!

Comment: You don't need the Select. You're trying to create a new instance of an EF entity inside a EF query using that entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, there is no difference both will find the record with that particular condition from Database.

In Second case you can do like this in one line with more readability instead of writing so many lines like that:

```
Bookings bookings = db.Bookings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.BookingsID == id);
```

or if you want to do that way then as well you can do like this:

```
Bookings bookings = (from tbBooking in db.Bookings
                     where tbBooking.BookingsID == id
                     select tbBooking).FirstOrDefault();
```

There is no need of creating new object as the properties are all same and also the type.

Answer (score 1):

1. logically, no difference.
2. performance wise, first one is better as the second one has repeated select
3. readability/maintenance wise, first one is better as it's more readable and easy to maintain
4. overrall, first one is better

Answer (score -1):

In First Case,

> Bookings bookings = db.Bookings.Find(id);

this is not the right way to do. Find should have same object as argument as list of object is.

For Example:
db.Bookings is List< Bookings >

Then code should be like this

```
Bookings bookings = db.Bookings.Find(bookingsObj);
```

OR

```
Bookings bookings = db.Bookings.Find(x=> x.BookingsID==id);
```